# CSS disabling the links on its own

Tags: html, css

My HTML and CSS are behaving weirdly. I have a div element named header in which I have a list of in-page links. When I apply CSS to the link or the div element, the links get disabled i.e. nothing 
happens on mouse click. I tried a lot but I'm not able to spot my error. Appreciate your help.

Here is my HTML component:

```
    <div class = "header">
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png" />
        <ul id = "nav">
            <li><a href="#homes">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tutorials">Tutorial</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#contacts">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS I'm trying to apply:

```css
.header{position:relative;width:950px; margin:0 auto; z-index: -1;}
.header #nav{float: right; margin-top:55px}
.header #nav li{float:left; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; line-height:12px; border-     right:1px solid #06F; list-style-type: none;}
.header #nav li.last{border-right:none;}
.header #nav li a{display: inline;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px; color:#081d58;}
.header #nav li a:hover{color:#253494;}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess your `z-index: -1;` is placing your links under another element like the `body` so that your links appear disabled.

Comment: it is the z index...take that out

Comment: also there is a space between your border- and right in the .header #nav li section of css

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you do not completely understand what href: "#homes" does. If you are on a website called www.mywebsite.com and you would use href: "#homes" it will keep you on the same page but scroll a div with the name #homes to the top of the page.

#homes will link your page to www.mywebsite.com#homes. My guess is that you want to open a new webpage called www.mywebsite.com/homes in which case you should change href to:

```
   <a href: "http://www.mywebsite.com/homes">Home</a>
```

Alternatively your #home div is not scrollable content, so the browser cannot move it to the top and your page stays the same.

Hope this solves your problem ^^